# How to get reference message id in slash commands discord.py 2.1.0

Tags: discord.py

I left programming discord.py bots in 1.7.3 and i came back now

In discord.py 1.7.3 i made a command that if you reply to a user's text it will translate his text to english but yesterday I discovered there are slash commands and wanted to implement them,
so i updated discord.py and tried to make a translate slash command:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import app_commands
from googletrans import Translator


class Translate(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("translate.py caricato")

    @app_commands.command()
    async def ping(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, ctx):
        await interaction.response.defer()
        text = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(ctx.message.reference.message_id)
        translator = Translator()
        translation = translator.translate(text.content, scr="autodetect", dest="en")
        await interaction.response.send_message(translation)


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Translate(client))
```

When i run the script i get the following error:

> discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'cogs.translate' raised an error: TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression

I tried adding self to  `async def ping(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, ctx):`
but it doesn't work i get the same error,
if i remove ctx my code wouldn't work since it's required in the command so i'm just very unsure on what to do

This is my old discord.py 1.7.3 script which works on the older version that has no slash commands:

```
@commands.command()
async def translate(self, ctx):
    text = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(ctx.message.reference.message_id)
    translator = Translator()
    translation = translator.translate(text.content, scr="autodetect", dest="en")
    await ctx.send(translation)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently you can't use ctx in slash commands.

To "update" my command to discord.py 2.0 i had to create a context_menu command.
So first i checked how to do a context_menu command in a cog:

https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/7823#issuecomment-1086830458

And then I implemented my old discord.py 1.7.3 code into the context_menu, so the result is this:

```
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands
from googletrans import Translator


class MyTranslator(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot) -> None:
        self.bot = bot
        self.ctx_menu = app_commands.ContextMenu(
            name='Translate to English',
            callback=self.translator_context_menu
        )
        self.bot.tree.add_command(self.ctx_menu)

    async def cog_unload(self) -> None:
        self.bot.tree.remove_command(self.ctx_menu.name, type=self.ctx_menu.type)

    @app_commands.guilds(ENTER_SERVER_ID)
    async def translator_context_menu(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, message: discord.Message) -> None:
        translation = Translator().translate(message.content, src="auto", dest="en")
        await interaction.response.send_message(translation.text, ephemeral=True)


async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(MyTranslator(bot), guilds=[discord.Object(id=ENTER_SERVER_ID)])
```